# Can a manifold be triangulated with minimal surfaces

Tags: riemannian-geometry, counterexamples

It is a fact stated as an exercise in chapter 9 of Lee's book "Riemannian Geometry" that any compact 2D manifold can be triangulated by geodesic triangles. Can one triangulate any compact Riemannian manifold by simplices whose faces are minimal hypersurfaces ?